# Manipulate dom element outside React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React component that renders HTML only on a small part of a HTML document.

From within the React component I need to replace an element, that exist outside the component, with a block of HTML.

No matter how much I'm googling this, I cannot find a straight way to accomplish this, I assume that it's because React's guidelines that naturally prescribe to use `ref` instead.

**How would I use `document.getElementById()` or anything similar to insert the following sample HTML block at the place of a certain div:**

```
<div>
    <div class='yellow'>YELLOW</div>
    <div class='green'>GREEN</div>
    <div class='blue'>BLUE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be done from within the component or you can pass props/state to the other components to determine whether or not to display the block.  Showing more code (the component in particular) might help your case here.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to the top level element of the html react renders. It will still include the id attribute and thus can still be referenced with document.getElementById

```
<div id="toReplace">
    <div className="yellow">YELLOW</div>
    <div className="blue">blue</div>
    <div className="red">red</div>
</div>

componentDidMount() { //or wherever
    document.getElementById('toReplace').append('more html');
}
```

Comment: The HTML got output as a string. But you got me on the right path, and found a solution that seems to work (see other anwer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "<div><div class='yellow'>YELLOW</div><div class='yellow'>GREEN</div><div class='yellow'>BLUE</div></div>"
document.getElementById('toReplace').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('toReplace').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
```